# Isn't the fact that we believe our minds are able to reason or find truth an axiom in itself?

Tags: epistemology

I am trying to prove or disprove this, but I seem to have faced a problem: the mere attempt to prove (or disprove) that our mind makes an assumption that we can find truth means I am assuming the very thing I am trying to prove. Since I am reasoning to find the proof (truth), this seems like an epistemic regress problem.

So how can we get around this?

Comment: Acting on a belief does not require assuming that the belief is true. And if such actions result in confirming the belief then it is confirmed without any epistemic regress.

Comment: It appears that you are using word "assumption" interchangeably with "proof", even though the two words mean different things. When we assume something, it's only because we cannot prove it. Specifically, we cannot prove that we possess the capacity to find the truth -- but we can (and should) assume that we do. Oh, and axiom *is* an assumption.

Comment: And, of course, you don't need to prove (to yourself?) that you made an assumption -- this you just know.

Comment: With your mind you grasp at your own mind, it's not necessary that our minds are able to reason or find truth is an axiom, in fact Kant spent most of his life and in his critique of pure reason to arrive at the opposite conclusion, therefore if you force it as an axiom and follow the same Kantian transcendental logic, your system would explode...

Comment: @Caspian You speak about the expistemic concepts "beliving", "reasoning", "axiom" and "truth". For me it is not clear how you use these words in order to state a clear question: Your question is wrapped in its long first sentence. It would be helpful to split this long sentence into some short sentences. And to make clear the logical link between these sentences.

Comment: @DoubleKnot could you explain how Kantian Transcendental logic could lead to the system would 'explode'?

Comment: corollary question: how could a person who is *bad* at reasoning, logic, evaluating evidence and so forth *discover* and *verify* that they are bad at those things?

Comment: @TKoL Relatedly, I often come up with extremely smart stuff in my dreams. But when I wake up it often turns out to be bullshit full of logical holes :(

Comment: First, how could what you suggest be an axiom?

How could the mere attempt to prove that our mind makes an assumption that we can find truth mean anything like your assumption of anything?

Comment: @Howwhye pure dogmatic reasoning is not truth itself which can self-assert its own necessary existence as Kant's *critique* concludes. Of course for details you need to dig in and understand with respect to what his logic is transcendental beyond...

Comment: No.  The full answer is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: In all seriousness, why would you mind dropping 'in itself' off the end of that?

Do you think that would things less clear, or more?

Would you mind Posting your idea of what an axiom is, or do you seriously believe everyone here shares the same view?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is an axiom of human thought, that human thought exists and that it can be useful. People who try to disagree with this axiom will turn insane, to the extent that such logical contradictions tend to lead to madness (especially when the contradiction rests at some foundational level as is the case here).

Comment: That human thought exists is a conclusion after perception, not an axiom.

Comment: @Marxos You mean, by introspection like in the cogito? The way I see it, perception alone tells one very little; it needs to be interpreted before it can mean anything. As you write yourself [almost]: "a conclusion [based on] a perception". But a conclusion is already a kind of thought. Now, if you need to think through your perceptions to establish that thinking exists, were you not assuming unconsciously right from the start of your reasoning that thoughts exists, and can be useful (for instance to interpret our perception correctly)?

Answer (score 3):

The existence of the continuum that makes the thought process a reason indicates that this is an axiom. If we do not accept this as an axiom, there is no aspect of human thought that we can adopt as meaningful, even partially. That's why we philosophize.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your argument goes something like this.

> Premise: Your mind is able to search for truth.
> Conclusion: Your mind is able to search for truth.
>
> Alternatively,
>
> Premise: Your mind is not able to search for truth.
> Premise: You can make logical conclusions about what is or is not possible.
> Conclusion: Even though you started with "your mind is not able to search for truth," because you made this logical conclusion it means your mind is able to search for truth.
>
> Therefore, no matter what premise you start with, it is always true you can search for truth because this is a foundational assumption.

And now you have concerns that this is self-referencing and doesn't "prove anything".

Let me leave you with some comments about why your concerns are unfounded (but worth exploring).

---

I would point out that logic is only an abstraction, a tool for how to think about the world. Writing down on paper a conclusion doesn't necessarily mean "the real world" works this way.

Rarely are things only true or false. Is a door opened or closed? What if it's halfway opened? In classical logic, the [law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) (LEM) applies that says that something is true or false. When working with foundational systems, it is often worth considering whether LEM should be allowed or not. Can you see how this applies to your question?

It is also possible that "rational thought" is not the only path to truth. Hales *Relativism and the Foundations of Philosophy* explores how some people arrive at truth through alternative experiences ("alternative" being both literal and figurative). Side-stepping logic introduces additional challenges and probably more skepticism than it's worth. I'm not advocating for dismissing all rational foundations, I just want to point out that there alternative belief structures.  Can you see how this applies to your question?

Third, if you haven't seen it, briefly read up on the [Gettier problem(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem). Perhaps it's possible you arrive at the correct conclusion for the wrong reasons. Is that really knowledge? Have you proven anything?

Fourth, It's probably worth considering the difference between foundational and coherentism epistemology. The foundational school of thought has a long history going back to classical Greek thinkers. This is how your question is structured, that there should be some "starting point" that truth follows from. Coherentism however explores knowledge as something structured less like a tree. You can have mutually reinforcing ideas without having a "first cause." (I'm trying to summarize a nuanced topic in a sentence, so forgive the sloppy notation). You can read more about coherentism on [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/coherentism-in-epistemology/) or [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justep-coherence/).

Last, and a little more lightly, I would leave you with an example from Moore and caution not to stress about this too much. Sometimes you just need to accept something doesn't have a clean succinct answer. Moore's answer to skepticism was to hold up his hand and say "my hand exists"! I will leave it up to you how that applies to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, this is the key:

> the mere attempt to prove (or disprove) [...] means I am assuming the very thing I am trying to prove [...]

You are right that this *"...seems like an epistemic regress problem"*. The precise problem is that *logic is circular*.

Let me explain.

First, *Logic* as such is the set of formal rules of thinking. Why "formal"? Because Logic is expressed as a formal system. There's no *informal logic*, what is informal is *Reason*. In simple words, we can say that Logic and Reason are the same thing: a couple of sets of rules that intersect, except that Reason represent the informal rules of thinking (how we think, how we commit mistakes, how do we fall into fallacies, etc.) and Logic is the formal set of rules (formalization (the use of precise terms, expressed in written form and following strict rules) implies a great deal of filtering of inconsistencies).

Second, how do we know that the rules of Logic are correct? We don't! But since they are logically consistent, and that they seem to express the way the world behaves, we just take them as truth. Logic is a model of the world, it is not the world, but it is the model that best fits the rules of the world for all of us.

Third, the rules of logic sustain themselves. That is the problem you are finding. On one hand, Logic is tautological, which is like saying "believe in me, because I am true; if such rule is logically consistent with me, it is logical". On the other hand, logic is circular, which is like saying *truth is true*.

So, the moment you and I discuss, we are not just disagreeing about something: *we agree that we disagree*. And why can we agree about that? Because you and me share the exact same logical foundations. Otherwise, no one would disagree with the rest, because there would be no shared common logical foundation upon which have a disagreement. In order to disagree about something, we should agree about something deeper.

The fact that Logic is circular and tautological does not decrease its value and potential. Tautologies and circularity are not bad per se. I would say that it is simpler to find rules that contradict themselves that to find rules that are consistent between themselves.

So, the very core, absolute, foundational set of axioms is Logic. Upon it, we can add more (like, for example, the rules of Chess), provided that they don't break the circularity of Logic.

From a different perspective, you've just found the same problem Russell did: *Logic is sustained upon itself*. But you don't have to believe him or me. Just try to do this: *find a rule that validates Logic*: it is impossible, unless such rule is a logical rule, which makes any validation a tautology.

Comment: Logic is not always circular.  It begins at the premises and ends at the conclusions.  If you can't agree to the premises, you need to understand who is wrong.  If you can't agree at the conclusions, you need to understand where the flaw in logical deduction is. And if you can't agree that people CAN be wrong, then you don't have logic at all.

Comment: @Marxos believe it or not, it is. For example, a simple induction is sustained upon a circular rule: it is true because logic is true, and Logic is true because it is true. We just don't assess the complete logical chain to the base because we assume truth at the base. "begins at the premises and ends at the conclusions" means you just don't look how it is linked to Logic.

Answer (score 1):

We reason. We find truths. Inserting belief into these activities is misguided. Along DoubleKnot’s comment (if I may interpret it), there is no extra capacity outside the mind or combination of mind and world whereby to sit and *believe* we do such activities. There is no such vantage. We just do them, unavoidably, simply. We don’t believe we reason or believe we find truths. We of course believe as well, and have complex interplays of all three. But not any where we believe we reason or believe we find truth. There are many pedestrian truths with no room for belief.

Reasoning and finding truth aren’t axioms, don’t require laying down axioms, nor could they.

You can’t possibly enter such a regress because there isn’t one.

I’m honestly not sure exactly which philosopher(s) to tie this to however. Maybe someone like Searle is close.

Comment: Was Descartes' cogito a rudimentary trial to show that there are no vantage points outside of the one you are talking about. Is that what he arrives to when he said 'cogito, ergo sum'?

Comment: @Howwhye He was searching for (or should we say faced with) the most secure piece of knowledge and building the rest upon it. That was his main philosophical method. Likewise we can't believe we exist/don't exist, and likewise cogito ergo sum is not an axiom. That would be silly, and it couldn't be so secure if it were. I think your comparison works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

In [*The Principle of Reason*](https://books.google.gg/books/about/The_Principle_of_Reason.html?id=rWDUmlA6M98C&redir_esc=y), after covering how Leibniz's [Principle of Sufficient Reason](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sufficient-reason/) applies to one's determinations of objective reality, Heidegger draws reason into the very foundation of being.  That is to say, that basic reasoning, logic, λόγος, is itself part of whatever 'being' is: as that from which actual *beings* arise.

> "being and ground/reason: the same. Simultaneously this meant: being:
> the a-byss." Page 111.

Being is abyssal, depthless, without ground, as is reason.  (Reason needs no reason.)

> "Only when we contemplated what λόγος meant for Heraclitus in early
> Greek thinking did it become clear that this word simultaneously names
> being and ground/reason, naming both in terms of their
> belonging-together." Page 112.

That reason needs no reason solves the epistemic regress problem.

OP: (paraphrasing) *the attempt to prove that our minds [reason] means I am assuming [reason] to find the proof, which seems like an epistemic regress problem. / Is the fact that we believe our minds are able to reason an axiom by itself?*

Without reasoning one would not be able to live or think, let alone believe anything.  Since reason is part of the nature of consciousness one cannot take reason out of the picture to consider how mind could operate without reason.  Minds do not just reason, they are embodiments of reason.

Comment: `one cannot take reason out of the picture to consider how mind could operate without reason` -- i don't think OP is suggesting that.

Comment: @TKoL Then there would be no reason to "attempt to prove( or disprove) that our mind makes an assumption that we can [reason]" since reason is fundamental. Reason establishes thought so for thought to question reason makes no sense.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense. After all, some people are *bad at reasoning*. How would you know if you're bad at reasoning, or bad at techniques to find truths or weed out falsehoods, if you never ask questions like this? I think the question is a perfectly pertinent one to ask. I don't think the correct conclusion will be "Actually, human reasoning is baseless and ineffective", but I think being able to articulate your thoughts on the matter is an important philosophical exercise.

Comment: @TKoL One could question whether one is reasoning effectively but not that one is 'trying out' reasoning and would like some proof that it works.